# Aggregate root creating child entities with new GUIDS

Tags: design-patterns, nhibernate, domain-driven-design, business-logic, aggregateroot

I generally use nHibernate to generate the unique ID's for my entities... but I am thinking about generating them in code? Consider the following example: (If I am doing something else wrong please point it out as I am new to DDD):

These are all the classes that would belong in the same assembly i.e. my domain model.

```
public interface AggregateRootState
{
    bool CanAddChild(); 
    bool CanModifyChild(); 
    bool CanDeleteChild(); 
}

public class AggregateRoot
{
    private AggregateRootState aggregateRootState; 

    public IList<ChildEntity> ChildEntityList {get; internal set;}

    public bool CanAddChild()
    {
        return aggregateRootState.CanAddChild(); 
    }

    public void AddChild(ChildEntityParameters childEntityParameters)
    {
        if (!CanAddChild())
            throw new NotImplementedException("aggregate root not in correct state."); 

        ChildFactory.CreateChildEntity(childEntityParameters);
    }

    public bool CanModifyChild()
    {
        return aggregateRootState.CanModifyChild(); 
    }

    public void ModifyChild(ChildEntityParameters childEntityParameters)
    {

        if (!CanModifyChild())
            throw new NotImplementedException("aggregate root not in correct state.");

        ChildEntity childEntity = ChildEntityList.First(c => c.Id == childEntityParameters.Id); 
        childEntity.Property1 = childEntityParameters.Property1; 
        childEntity.Property2 = childEntityParameters.Property2; 
    }

    public bool CanDeleteChild()
    {
        return aggregateRootState.CanDeleteChild(); 
    }

    public void DeleteChild(Guid Id)
    {
        if (!CanDeleteChild())
            throw new NotImplementedException("aggregate root not in correct state");

        ChildEntityList.Remove(ChildEntityList.First(c => c.Id == Id));
    }

    public void Validate()
    {
        //code to validate the object and ensure it is in a savable state. 
    }
}

public class ChildEntityParameters
{
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public string Property1 {get; set;}
    public string Property2 {get; set;}
}

public class ChildEntity
{
    internal ChildEntity() { }
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public string Property1 {get; internal set;}
    public string Property2 {get; internal set;}
}

internal static class ChildFactory
{
    public static void CreateChildEntity(ChildEntityParameters childEntityParameters)
    {
        ChildEntity childEntity = new ChildEntity(); 
        childEntity.Property1 = childEntityParameters.Property1; 
        childEntity.Property2 = childEntityParameters.Property2; 
    }
}
```

My Service Layer would then look something like this:

```
//for simplicity I have arguments rather than using the request / response pattern. 
public class ServiceLayer
{
    public void AddChildEntity(Guid aggregateRootId, string string1, string string2)
    {
        AggregateRoot aggregateRoot = aggregateRootRepository.FindBy(aggregateRootId);
        ChildEntityParameters childEntityParameters = new ChildEntityParameters();
        childEntityParameters.Property1 = string1;
        childEntityParameters.Property2 = string2;
        aggregateRoot.AddChild(childEntityParameters); 
        aggregateRoot.Validate(); //will throw exception if there is something wrong. 
        aggregateRootRepository.Save(aggregateRoot);
    }
}
```

Now this all works well and good. However the problem is what if I wanted to return the ID of the newly created ChildEntity to the presentation layer? It's not currently possible. I would have to return the whole object graph. The only alternative I can think of is to make the following changes to my code:

```
internal static class ChildFactory
{
    public static void CreateChildEntity(ChildEntityParameters childEntityParameters)
    {
        ChildEntity childEntity = new ChildEntity(); 
        **childEntity.Id = Guid.NewGuid();**  
        childEntity.Property1 = childEntityParameters.Property1; 
        childEntity.Property2 = childEntityParameters.Property2; 
    }
}

public class ServiceLayer
{
    public **Guid** AddChildEntity(Guid aggregateRootId, string string1, string string2)
    {
        **Guid Id;** 
        AggregateRoot aggregateRoot = aggregateRootRepository.FindBy(aggregateRootId);
        ChildEntityParameters childEntityParameters = new ChildEntityParameters();
        childEntityParameters.Property1 = string1;
        childEntityParameters.Property2 = string2;
        **Id = aggregateRoot.AddChild(childEntityParameters);** 
        aggregateRoot.Validate(); //will throw exception if there is something wrong. 
        aggregateRootRepository.Save(aggregateRoot);
        return Id; 
    }
}
```

Is this wrong? or is it perfectly ok? Would be good if someone could clarify!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my solution in the end. When save is executed the ID will be populated for the child object. Since I have a reference to the Child object I can then return the ID. Being new to DDD I wasn't aware that you could pass around child entities... but after doing some further reading I stumbled on the following rule from Eric Evans:

> The root Entity can hand reference to the internal ENTITIES to other objects, but those objects can only use them transiently, and may not hold onto the reference.

```
public class ServiceLayer
{
    public **Guid** AddChildEntity(Guid aggregateRootId, string string1, string string2)
    {
        **ChildObject obj;** 
        AggregateRoot aggregateRoot = aggregateRootRepository.FindBy(aggregateRootId);
        ChildEntityParameters childEntityParameters = new ChildEntityParameters();
        childEntityParameters.Property1 = string1;
        childEntityParameters.Property2 = string2;
        **obj = aggregateRoot.AddChild(childEntityParameters);** 
        aggregateRoot.Validate(); //will throw exception if there is something wrong. 
        aggregateRootRepository.Save(aggregateRoot);
        return obj.Id; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Vaughn Vernon's excellent [book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Implementing-Domain-Driven-Design-Vaughn-Vernon/dp/0321834577) suggests that an appropriate strategy for creating entities is that they arrive fully-formed with an identity, opposed to being created in a transient state, I suppose. Therefore, I think you're on the right line by ensuring that the child is creating with it's id.

This also solves a tricky little problem where obtaining the hashcode of a transient object doesn't always return the same hashcode for an equivalent persisted object.

Comment: I will have to look into that book as it seems to be referenced quite a fair bit. 

So you're suggesting I should generate the ID when the object is created for all my entities? including the aggregate root? 

After posting the original question I did some further research and found that if you specify an ID then nHibernate doesn't know whether to insert or update the record? Is this just a matter of changing the configuration in nhibernate?

Comment: Can't you ask NH to generate the Id for you via `Save()`? Or alter your mapping so that id = assigned?

Comment: I am now confused. 

If I get NH to generate the Id for me via Save() I am back to the original problem in that I can't get the ID of the newly created child entity? 

So I guess I would have to change the mapping so that id = assigned. There are issues with this as mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048728/fluent-nhibernate-generated-and-assigned-id-columns

but I don't really see an alternative? 

Bad design decision according to: http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-id-assigned